# Updating array items angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularfire

I am using angularfire $add method to add basic js objects of the form {id:integer,name:name}
Now, if I want to update a particular item (which usually has a firebase-assigned key like   "-JEcA_f70efHbKi5js7j" or something, my impression is that I should use the $save method.
Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
$scope.chosenColors = $firebase(myChosenColorsRef);


$scope.updateColor = function(data){ //data is a JS object like {id:'id',name:'name'}

    if($scope.chosenColors.$getIndex().length>0){
        var keys = $scope.chosenColors.$getIndex();
        keys.forEach(function(key, i) { 
            if($scope.chosenColors[key].id!=data.id){//if id matches I want to update name
                $scope.chosenColors[key] = {id:data.id,name:data.name}
                $scope.chosenColors.$save[key];
                return;
            }
        });
    }else{
        $scope.chosenColors.$add(data);         
    }
```

But this doesn't appear to have any effect on the firebase...any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should call the `$save` method instead of simply accessing it with a key:

```
$scope.chosenColors.$save(key);
```

Secondly, you're iterating over all the keys to figure out which one you want to save which is pretty inefficient. You should change your updateColor argument to take the `key` as an argument.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, color) in chosenColors">
  <a ng-click="updateColor(key, color)">Update</a>
  ...
</div>

function updateColor(key, data) {
  $scope.chosenColors[key] = data;
  $scope.chosenColors.$save(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. I will give it a go.. the reason I am iterating over all items is I am responding to a drag event on a canvas item, and I need to know which item it is that is being dragged...I suppose I could keep that as part of the dragged object and address it directly..baby steps!
Regards,

Comment: I think this should have been a comment, instead of an answer.